# Spring Boot Microservices - Add authorization header to restTemplate.getForObject

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, bearer-token

I have a problem in defining bearer token in restTemplate.getForObject in OrderServiceImpl and OrderServiceImplTest of order service. The problem is located at **getOrderDetails** of **OrderServiceImpl**,  **test_When_Order_Success** and **test_When_Get_Order_NOT_FOUND_then_Not_Found** of OrderServiceImplTest.

Here is the code snippets shown below.

```
 @Override
    public OrderResponse getOrderDetails(long orderId, String bearerToken) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+ bearerToken);

        // How can I add bearer token in here
        ProductResponse productResponse
                = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class
        );

        // How can I add bearer token in here
        PaymentResponse paymentResponse
                = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class
        );

        ....
}
```

Here is the test method shown below.

```
    @DisplayName("Get Order - Success Scenario")
    @Test
    void test_When_Order_Success() {

        String bearerToken = "";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+ bearerToken);

        //Mocking
        Order order = getMockOrder();
        when(orderRepository.findById(anyLong()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(order));

        when(restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class
        )).thenReturn(getMockProductResponse());

        when(restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class
        )).thenReturn(getMockPaymentResponse());

        //Actual
        OrderResponse orderResponse = orderService.getOrderDetails(1,bearerToken);

        //Verification
        verify(orderRepository, times(1)).findById(anyLong());
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class);
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class);

        //Assert
        assertNotNull(orderResponse);
        assertEquals(order.getId(), orderResponse.getOrderId());
    }
```

How can I define bearer token in these methods?

Here is the OrderServiceImpl : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/master/orderservice/src/main/java/com/microservice/orderservice/service/impl/OrderServiceImpl.java)

Here is the OrderServiceImplTest : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/master/orderservice/src/test/java/com/microservice/orderservice/service/OrderServiceImplTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

The getForObject() method of RestTemplate does not support headers. You should use the exchange() method provided by the RestTemplate class.